# Resolving a parent component's props at child's context (instead of parent's)

Tags: reactjs

I want to implement a list in React such that it takes in a component as for each row it's going to render. Here's what I've got now:

```
class List extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return (<div>
            {this.props.Items.map(function(item) {
                return Object.assign({}, this.props.RowCmp, { item: item });
            })}
        </div>);
    }
}

List.PropTypes = {
    Items: ReactPropTypes.array.isRequired,
    RowCmp: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};


class ListImpl extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <List
                Items={[{f: 1}, {f: 2}, {f: 3}]}
                RowCmp={<div>{this.props.item.f}</div>}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

The problem with this implementation is that in `ListImpl` where I want to define the `RowCmp` I need to point to a `prop` which belongs to `List` but it will be resolved in `ListImpl` context.

How can I define a component as a prop which it's props will be resolved at child's context?

**[UPDATE]**

Think of the `RowCmp` as a template for the `List` component in order to render each row.

Comment: I think some wires are getting crossed here... if `List` is a child of `ListImpl` then all of the relevant props will originate from `ListImpl` not `List`. Also `ListImpl` should definitely not extend `List`, that must be a mistake, right?

Comment: The sample code is as I intended, and you've got one thing wrong. The `ListImpl` is trying to implement `List` which means `ListImpl` is the child. And it needs to come up with implementation for `RowCmp`.

Comment: I think you're confused about how React is designed.. in your code above, `<List />` is a child of `ListImpl` because it is *called* inside `ListImpl`'s render method. In React you do not extend other components... the `class` syntax is confusing I guess, but it's nothing like C# or Java classes.. you should only be extending `React.Component`

Comment: I'm sorry you are absolutely right. I've been in a rush and made a terrible mistake. I'll fix it right away. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself:

```
class ListImpl extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <List
                Items={[{f: 1}, {f: 2}, {f: 3}]}
                RowCmp={
                    class extends React.Component {
                        render() {
                            return (
                                <div>{this.props.item.f}</div>
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            />
        );
    }
}
```